# Should I write tests for class A if it's covered from class B

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'd like to get some opinion about testing methodology.

Lets assume we have class A and B. Class B uses functionality of class A. The B class is fully tested and thus some test coverage is also applied indirectly for class A.

Should I write full tests directly for class A? Or should I test only not tested A class functionality?

I am asking because maybe in the future there will be possibility that the B class will be removed or modified in the way that it might not use the same functionality from A class so it might leave some methods untested. What would you do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### CLASSES != UNITS

### If you practice a good TDD, you will understand easily what is behind.

---

IMO, you should test `B`'s behavior without based on the fact that `A` would already be tested.

Actually, there are three cases:

`A` and `B` BELONGING TO THE SAME LAYER:

- If `A` is created through refactor cycle (extract class) of `B` (happens often while practicing a good TDD), then `A` should TOTALLY be left untested! No need to test it at all!
  Indeed, structure of code (in this case, separation of classes/SRP) should be independent of **Unit** concept; `B` and `A` in this case belonging to the same unit.
- If `A` existed **BEFORE** `B`, `B` should not be based on this fact, and `B`'s whole behavior should be tested.

`A` and `B` NOT BELONGING TO THE SAME LAYER (distinct [boundaries](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) for instance):

- If `B` is a GUI class, and `A` a business class, then `A` should be doubled/mocked when testing `B`, and also `A` should have a full test dedicated for it.
  Indeed, domain architecture should not be mingled with `behavior/feature` notion.

To understand why, read this recent article of Uncle Bob dealing with this concept:

http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/01/27/TheChickenOrTheRoad.html?utm_source=hootsuite&utm_campaign=hootsuite

Excerpt of it:

> It is a common misconception that the design of the tests must mirror
>   the design of the production code. TDD does not require, as the Author
>   suggests, "that every unit in your system is paired with a
>   well-designed [...] unit test." Indeed, that's one of the reasons that
>   many of us have stopped calling them "unit" tests.

Note: TDD doesn't care about "future", in the contrary, it helps you to write as much code as you need, no more. Therefore you should not worry about this:

> in the future there will be possibility that the B class will be
>   removed or modified

If you wrote good tests (I prefer the word "specs"), such removal would be detected immediately.

Comment: "If A existed BEFORE B ... B's whole behavior should be tested." You mean A's whole behaviour?

Comment: @tobi No, my sentence is correct. What I meant is: if A existed before B, it's not a reason to make a partial test of B, supposing that some things in common are already tested in the test for A. In both cases, either "before" or "after", B business rules are tested entirely.

Comment: @Mik378 I realize this is an old answer, but in the second case you described then it will be possible for a bug to cause more than one test to fail, which I thought was against a unit testing "best practice." How to avoid that?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you should fully test `A`.

1. `B` might change at some point down the road, so just because it uses `A` now doesn't mean that it always will.
2. `B` may not use all of the functionality of `A` which means that you're not testing all of your code.

Comment: It sounds like you're arguing that units == classes. With this philosophy, you'll end up with a lot of duplicate coverage, resulting in the problems described in this post http://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2014-01-25-the-failures-of-intro-to-tdd.html.

Comment: @JeremyRoss - I'm certainly not equating classes to units. I'm merely pointing out that relying on inter-dependencies between classes for test coverage will lead to issues in the future. It'd be better to have those dependencies mocked and then test each unit individually to ensure complete coverage in the future.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Uncle Bob explains exactly the contrary of your opinion: http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/01/27/TheChickenOrTheRoad.html?utm_source=hootsuite&utm_campaign=hootsuite

Answer (score 5):

Definately write full tests for class A. You kind of answered your own question here:

`(...)maybe in the future there will be possibility that the B class will be removed or modified in the way that it might not use the same functionality from A class so it might leave some methods untested.`

Answer (score 5):

The general thought behind unittesting is that each unit is comprised of a Unit of Work. This can be as small as a method or as big as several methods working together.

You have already covered the scenario where B is dependent on A but from your story we can assume A will also be used separately. Therefore A should also be tested since it is a separate Unit of Work.

Comment: The word "Unit" is not as Unit as it expects: http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/01/27/TheChickenOrTheRoad.html?utm_source=hootsuite&utm_campaign=hootsuite

Comment: Can you clarify what you're referring to?

Comment: As my answer explains in this topic, it's quite possible that `A` is only the result of a refactoring (extract class), and in this case, logically all it's behavior has ALREADY been tested implicitly by its callers while testing their behaviors. If this is the case, then I would not test `A` at all since code structure (refactoring) is independent of behavior.

Answer (score 4):

B should only use A through an Interface IA

Test B through it's public interface and A through it's public interface.

Both should be tested.

Answer (score 3):

I think your answer is right there:
`in the future there will be possibility that the B class will be removed or modified`
I think that's a strong case for a testsuite for A.

Answer (score 3):

You should *first* test A, *then* B. If you get a test failure on B, you won't have enough diagnostic to know whether it originated in B's code or in A's.

Unit tests are not just about "pass/fail", they are very much about *diagnosing the problem*.

Comment: "You should first test A, then B" > Uncle Bob would disagree with your answer http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/01/27/TheChickenOrTheRoad.html?utm_source=hootsuite&utm_campaign=hootsuite

Comment: My major takeaway from that article is that the guy sure can talk a lot.