# Unit testing classes through other test classes

Tags: oop, unit-testing, tdd

Suppose I am using TDD to create some class A. After I am done and have a "green" bar, I decide that I want to extract some class B with only static methods from class A using some refactoring tool. I now have class A and class B both fully unit tested, but only through the test class for class A. Should I also now create a test class specific to functionality of class B, even though that would be duplicating test?

Comment: Duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482602/should-i-write-tests-for-class-a-if-its-covered-from-class-b/21482748#21482748

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As always, it depends on your context. What do you care about?

**Overall behaviour**

If you're building a system for internal use, or even a public (web) service, where the software you're shipping is the entire system, you don't have to care too much about a single class. **If you're building a system, then test the system.**

As long as it's covered by tests, you know that your system behaves correctly. However, you may run into a situation that after some months, you realize that you no longer need the original `A` class, so you delete it and its corresponding unit tests. This may cause test coverage of `B` to drop, so it may be a good idea to keep an eye on code coverage trends.

**Unit behaviour**

If you're building a (class) library, or framework, you're shipping each public class as part of the product. If you have multiple users of your library, you'll need to start thinking about how to avoid breaking changes.

One of the most effective ways to avoid breaking changes is to cover each class by unit tests. As long as you [don't change the tests](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/02/why-trust-tests), you know that breaking changes are unlikely if all tests are green. However, that requires that you test all your public classes and members.

Thus, if you extract `B` to a public class, it's now a class that other consumers may depend on, and it would be a breaking change if you change it. Therefore, you should cover it with new tests. **If you're building a unit, then test the unit.**

Comment: I addition to Marks answer I would like to add that creating such a class as B is a code smell to me. It doesn't have to be that way of course, but chances are that its purpose will be unclear, and probably is in violation of the SOLID principles. If you find yourself having problems naming the class, that's probably the case.

Comment: @spacedoom Isn't that a bit harsh? Extracting a class from another class can be a perfectly valid Refactoring. The fact that in this case it's static may be a code smell, but since I know that you're an F# fan, perhaps a static class is just a functional module waiting to materialize. However, SOLID it isn't, I agree with that :)

Comment: I certainly didn't intend to be harsh, just giving and object oriented comment to an oop tagged question. I didn't pick on extracting classes in general, just classes like B. I'm pretty certain its name is going to be something lika AHelper, and we don't want that, do we?
Anyway, you're damn right it would be better if it was written as functional modules in F#! :)

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described the answer is to create another new test.  If either changes by you (or someone else who is not familiar with the "shared test") the other class will in no longer be tested.

If this seems wasteful, put the common test code in a third class...