# Java decouple database manipulation code & make it testable

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns

I want to write a **test** for the following method:

```
public void addItem(Item item) {

    items.add(0, item);
    DatabaseHelper.getInstance().writeOneItem(item);
}
```

The class is called ItemManager and it's responsibility is to manage Items that the user can save to or remove from a list. It should be kept in sync with an Sqlite database that persists the items on the list.

When the `DatabaseHelper` (ormlite) is not inited with `init(Context context)` (which is usually sone when my Andoid app starts, but is not done in my test), it's `getInstance()` method will return `null` and the method execution from above will crash.

What should I do here? I could just call `init(Context context)` from my test or check if `DatabaseManager.getInstance()` is null before calling anything on it. But that seems more like a workaround. It seems to me like I shouldn't do any Database stuff in this method and try to seperate the ItemManager from the Database as much as possible.

Any ideas on how the ideal solution would look, not in form of a concrete implementation but from a gerneral design standpoint?

I'm new to unit testing and having a hard time decoupling stuff from each other.

Comment: This tends to be one of the main reasons for using dependency injection. i.e. Don't use static methods. Create a singleton DatabaseHelper instance and inject that into instances of classes that need it. That way, when testing you can inject a stub/mock database helper instance.

Comment: You should look at the "D" of SOLID principle to increase your ability to write testable code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing on code that uses the Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391249/unit-testing-on-code-that-uses-the-database)

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, your class `ItemManager` has to call the `DatabaseHelper` to write the item but your unit test just want to make sure that it does. You don't want to test that the `DatabaseHelper` actually writes the item in the database, that would be another test.

I would modify the design of your class: the `DatabaseHelper.getInstance()` should not be done directly in the method. Your `ItemManager` should have a private field with the instance of the `DatabaseHelper`. That way you can mock it and verify that it is called.

Using [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) for example:

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    items.add(0, item);
    this.databaseHelper.writeOneItem(item);
}

@Test
public void my_test() {
    // GIVEN
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = mock(DatbaseHelper.class);
    ItemManager manager = new ItemManager(databaseHelper);
    Item item = new Item()

    // WHEN
    manager.addItem(item);

    // THEN
    verify(databaseHelper).writeOneItem(item); // This verifies that the method writeOneItem of the "mock" is called with the "item" parameter
}

// Another test would check that the item is added to the "items" collection
```

Your unit test should be focused on testing ONE method and not the behaviour of the classes it uses.

In my example, I inject the `DatabaseHelper` in the `ItemManager` via constructor but you could use any method: constructor, setter, dependency injection framework, etc.

Comment: Your unit test should be focused on testing ONE method > your unit test should be focused on behaviour, not method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482602/should-i-write-tests-for-class-a-if-its-covered-from-class-b/21482748#21482748

Answer (score 3):

Break the static dependance and use a mock framework (like mockito)

```
class ItemManager {
 ...
 // decoupling
 private DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();

 public void addItem(Item item) {
    items.add(0, item);
    instance.writeOneItem(item);
 }
}
```

With mockito :

```
class ItemManagerTest{
 // declare mock service
 @Mock
 DatabaseHelper instance;

 // inject mock service into your about to be tested class
 @InjectMocks
 ItemManager manager;

 @Test
 public void test() {
  // Given
  Item item = new Item();
  ...

  // When
  manager.addItem(item);

  // Then
  // assert that the service has been called with the right parameters
  verify(instance).writeOneItem(item);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create you own class that wrap the DatabaseHelper, let say you call it MyDBLayer

```
class abstract MyDBLayer {
    public void writeOneItem(Item item);
}

class OrmLiteDBLayer {
    public void writeOneItem(Item item) {
        DatabaseHelper.getInstance().writeOneItem(item);
    }
}

class FakeDBLayer {
    public void writeOneItem(Item item) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Than you could inject FakeDBLayer in test and OrmLiteDBLayer in production.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to test the behaviour of the method i.e. if `items` actually contains the new item, not if the data is written to the database.

I'd use dependency injection and a mock object.

Using something like `DatabseHelper.getInstance()` is definitely convenient, but hard to test. I'd change the to test to

```
public class ClassToTest {

  private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

  public void setDatabaseHelper(DatabaseHelper databaseHelper) {
    this.databaseHelper = databaseHelper;
  }

  public void addItem(Item item) {
    items.add(0, item);
    databaseHelper.writeOneItem(item);
  }
}
```

Next, I'd introduce an interface `IDatabaseHelper` with the method `void writeOneItem(Item item)` and let DatabaseHelper implement this interface. Additionally, I'd create a MockDatabaseHelper that also implements the interface.

In your regular code you'd then use

```
ClassToTest myClass = new ClassToTest();
myClass.setDatabaseHelper(DatabaseHelper.getInstance());
```

and in your Test you'd use

```
ClassToTest myClass = new ClassToTest();
myClass.setDatabaseHelper(new MockDatabaseHelper());
```

The implementation in the `MockDatabaseHelper` could empty or be a simple log statement. If your class uses other methods from `DatabaseHelper`, you need to add these the interface as well and add an implementation to MockDatabaseHelper that mimicks the behaviour of the real DatabaseHelper.

As others already have mentioned, there are mock frameworks that save you some of the work with writing MockObjects.
Additionally, I'd recommend to check out [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) in general.