# mock non static method of object which is created not in test method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

Is it possible in this case to mock RentalProfile.getStartDate() with Mockito, PowerMock or any other mock objects generator?

I tried to do somewhat like this but it did not work:

```
@Test
public void testsetAmortizationModel() throws Exception {
    // ...
    RentalProfile mock = Mockito.mock(RentalProfile.class);
    Mockito.when(mock.getStartDate()).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
        @Override
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return "2014-12-21";
        }
    });
    Mockito.verify(mock);
    // ...

}
```

And there is method where RentalProfile.getStartDate() is called. It does not return "2014-12-21":

```
public void classMethod() {
    List<RentalProfile> tPaymentPlans =
    aCompositeAgreement.getRentalProfiles().getRentalProfile();
// ...
    for (RentalProfile tRentalProfile : tPaymentPlans) {
        LocalDate tStartDate = BridgeDateUtils.stringWithHyphenToDate(
            tRentalProfile.getStartDate()); // tRentalProfile is RentalProfile object
// ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `tRentalProfile` is the same instance as `mock`? It should work if it's the same instance. When you mock a class, you create a mock instance that you have to use in your test. It won't modify the behavior of all the instances of this class.

Comment: Also you can simplify the mocking: `when(mock.getStartDate()).thenReturn("2014-12-21");`

Comment: Made some edits. this is how `tRentalProfile` is created.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the code you've posted:

1. As Vincent advised, you can simplify the mocking by replacing `Mockito.when(...).thenAnswer(...)` with `when(mock.getStartDate()).thenReturn("2014-12-21")`
2. `Mockito.verify(mock);` is not required here as it's usually used to check whether a particular method (with expected parameters) has been called on the mock.
3. You are nowhere showing that the mock is injected in your class instance to facilitate the testing.

The following example class will run correctly and inject the dependency for your test:

```
public class MyClass {

   private RentalProfile tRentalProfile = null;

   public MyClass(RentalProfile tRentalProfile) {
      this.tRentalProfile = tRentalProfile;
   }

  public void classMethod() {
    // ...
    LocalDate tStartDate = BridgeDateUtils.stringWithHyphenToDate(
      tRentalProfile.getStartDate()); // tRentalProfile is RentalProfile object injected to MyClass
    // ...
  }

}
```

Now this can be mocked with Mockito in the following way:

```
@Test
public void testsetAmortizationModel() throws Exception {
    // ...
    RentalProfile mock = Mockito.mock(RentalProfile.class);
    Mockito.when(mock.getStartDate()).thenReturn("2014-12-21");

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(mock);
    myClass.classMethod();

    // Here you verify whether method has been successfully executed 
    // i.e. verify return value, other class parameters,, mock method calls etc.

}
```

Comment: The point is that I test another class methods but some of them has local RentalProfile object which is needed to be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the mock instance created in your test is not used.

```
@Test
public void testsetAmortizationModel() throws Exception {
    // ...
    RentalProfile mock = Mockito.mock(RentalProfile.class);
    when(mock.getStartDate()).thenReturn("2014-12-21");
    Mockito.verify(mock);
    // ...

    MyClass classToTest = new MyClass(mock);
    classToTest.myMethod();
}
```

And your class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private RentalProfile profile;

    public MyClass(RentalProfile profile) { this.profile = profile; }

    public void myMethod() {
        for (RentalProfile tRentalProfile : tPaymentPlans) {
            LocalDate tStartDate = BridgeDateUtils.stringWithHyphenToDate(
                this.profile.getStartDate());
        }
    }
}
```

You have to decouple the creation of the variables. What you really want to test is not the creation of the `RentalProfile`, it is of your method reacts if it returns this value.

In my example, I chose to inject the profile via constructor.

Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135757/2015239
It is exactly the same problem: you have to decouple the code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but the bad thing is that I can only change test code.
By the way, I made a stupid mistake in my post. `classMethod()` has a private access type. Would your code work the same if I invoke this method with `Whitebox.invokeMethod(Class<?> class, Object... arguments)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock an object that is created inside the code under test as follows, using the JMockit library:

```
@Test
public void testSetAmortizationModel(@Mocked final RentalProfile mock)
{
    new Expectations() {{ mock.getStartDate(); result = "2014-12-21"; }};

    // No need to pass "mock" into the SUT here; any future instance will be mocked.
    MyClass classToTest = new MyClass();
    classToTest.myMethod();
}
```